# Firestore: request for a list of collection IDs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Firestore documentation says:][1]

> ###Queries other than document reads
> For queries other than document reads, such as a request for a list of collection IDs, you are billed
> for one document read. If fetching the complete set of results
> requires more than one request (for example, if you are using
> pagination), you are billed once per request.

I cannot find any information of how to perform such queries to get only IDs.

Does anyone know how?
[1]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbled across this question as I read the exact same documentation and wanted to know the same. As of now (27 Dec 2021) I *believe* that the appropriate method is [listDocuments](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#listDocuments)

*EDIT*
It should be noted that the call mentioned in the link above would result in you being charged a read *per document ID returned*. So tread carefully

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30683058)

Comment: @JeremyCaney looks like you are right, unfortunately though, it each document reference seems to be counted as one document read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62007048/firebase-cloud-firestore-listdocuments-doc-read-cost-1-or-n-possible-alterna

Comment: @ZuzEL Well shucks - that sucks, thanks for linking though, as per that question I was also thinking it could be a "cheap" way to get a count. 

Answer (score 4):

You can get the collection IDs using the REST API.  The documentation is [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/listCollectionIds)

You can also return an array of collection IDs with `documentRef.getCollections()` as detailed [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.11.x/DocumentReference#getCollections)