# Flutter: How can I retrieve all Collections from cloud_firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I'm able to retrieve specific collections, but I want to retrieve them all and put them into a dropdown button. I also need to be able to create a Collection client-side.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258632/fetching-all-collections-in-firestore, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903472/firestore-request-for-a-list-of-collection-ids

Answer (score 1):

There is no mobile client API on any platform that lists collections.  There is only [an API in the admin SDK](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.14.x/Firestore#getCollections), which is not meant to be used on mobile clients.

There is no API to create a collection by itself.  A collection will be created the moment you write a document into it, and it will suddenly cease to exist after the last document is delete from it.

Answer (score 0):

Move your collections out of the root node and under a document node. Then you can fetch/get all that documents subcollections.

See [List subcollections of a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document)

> The getCollections() method of the Cloud Firestore server client
>   libraries lists all subcollections of a document reference.

Comment: So you're saying I should have one high level collection and use my documents as  collections with their own collections and documents?

Comment: I'm saying that you can fetch all the child collections of a specific document node, but you cannot fetch all the child collections from the root node. So, it seems you can do what you want, provided you nest your collections under a document.

Comment: @RonRoyston i think this is not works with flutter. Because getCollection() method is not for flutter.